# I keep getting an error incompatible type , Required android.widget.spinner, found int

Tags: java, android

i want the method to store the result of the onItemSelected from an array of strings to an int and store it in the database

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {     

String selection = (String)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(selection)){
    if (selection.equals("Critical")){
        mySpinner = storeEntry.PRIORITY_CRITICAL;
    }else if (selection.equals("Important")){
        mySpinner = storeEntry.PRIORITY_IMPORTANT;
    }else if (selection.equals("Casual")){
        mySpinner = storeEntry.PRIORITY_CASUAL;
    }else {
        mySpinner = storeEntry.PRIORITY_NORMAL;
    }
 }
}
@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    mySpinner = storeEntry.PRIORITY_NORMAL;

}
```

i want to get over that error

Comment: I will assume you want to switch the selected value of your spinner. Change **mySpinner =  to mySpinner.setSelection(storeEntry...);** or store the integers **(i.e storeEntry.PRIORITY_NORMAL)** in an integer variables instead of **mySpiner**. Error occurs because you cannot assign an integer to Spinner object

Comment: @GiddyNaya actually he's doing this in `onItemSelected` so it looks like he just confused the integer name with view object name.

Comment: `mySpinner` obviously is not an `int`

Answer (score 1):

You are just confusing the name of View with variable.

**mySpinner** is your View. You probably made another variable to store id of currently selected item. Use that integer instead of `mySpinner`.

It would look something like this:

```
int mySpinnerSelection = storeEntry.PRIORITY_NORMAL; //Assuming priority is integer

public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {     

String selection = (String)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(selection)){
    if (selection.equals("Critical")){
        mySpinnerSelection = storeEntry.PRIORITY_CRITICAL;
    }else if (selection.equals("Important")){
        mySpinnerSelection = storeEntry.PRIORITY_IMPORTANT;
    }else if (selection.equals("Casual")){
        mySpinnerSelection = storeEntry.PRIORITY_CASUAL;
    }else {
        mySpinnerSelection = storeEntry.PRIORITY_NORMAL;
    }
 }
}
@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    mySpinnerSelection = storeEntry.PRIORITY_NORMAL;

}
```